# Как правильно изменить класс у объекта?

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Прошу помочь разобраться в питоне,
есть родительский класс и дочерний

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo()
        self.aaa = 'aaa'

    def foo(self):
        print('child foo')
```

Где-то в начале кода автоматически создается объект родительского класса с некоторыми атрибутами

```
obj = Parent()
obj.x = 322
obj.y = 69
```

Далее мне нужно ***к уже созданному*** этому объекту добавить методы и атрибуты дочернего класса, я делаю примерно так

```
...
obj.__class__ = Child
obj.__class__()
print(obj.__dir__())
obj.aaa # AttributeError
```

и получаю вывод:

```
child foo
['x', 'y', '__module__', '__init__', 'foo', '__doc__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__new__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__getstate__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\BACK\izg\4444.py", line 28, in <module>
    obj.aaa # AttributeError
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'aaa'
```

То есть у объекта сохранились атрибуты родителя `x` и `у`, добавился новый дочерний метод `foo`, но не добавился дочерний атрибут `aaa`, который мне нужен.

Почему? И как его сейчас получить в объекте?

UPD: уточняю вопрос, в объекте нужно сохранить `x, y` и добавить к нему `foo(), aaa`

Comment: Лучше вообще всё реализовать по-другому. Менять класс на ходу - грязный хак, который ни к чему хорошему не приведёт. Присваивать объекту напрямую новые аттрибуты, которые никак не управляются его классом - плохая практика, которая ни к чему хорошему не приведёт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Как правильно изменить класс у объекта?

Правильно - никак. Перезапись поля `__class__` - это грязный хак.

Используйте композицию вместо наследования. Если нужно иметь доступ к полям первого объекта из второго объекта, то положите первый объект во второй как отдельный атрибут:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent: Parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.foo()
        self.aaa = 'aaa'

    def foo(self):
        print('child foo')


obj = Parent()
obj.x = 322
obj.y = 69

child = Child(obj)
print(child.aaa)
print(child.parent.x)
print(child.parent.y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто нужно было вызвать `__init__`:

```py
obj.__class__ = Child
obj.__class__.__init__(obj)
print(obj.__dir__())
print(obj.x, obj.y, obj.aaa, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
child foo
['x', 'y', 'aaa', '__module__', '__init__', 'foo', '__doc__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__new__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
322
69
aaa
```

Но вообще лучше и правда такого не делать. Но если очень хочется, то вот.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в родительском классе этот атрибут. Он будет доступен и для класса родителя, и для класса наследника.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.aaa = "aaa"


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo()

    def foo(self):
        print('child foo')


obj = Parent()
obj.x = 322
obj.y = 69

obj.__class__ = Child
obj.__class__()
print(obj.__dir__())
print(obj.aaa)
```

Результат:

```
['aaa', 'x', 'y', '__module__', '__init__', 'foo', '__doc__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__new__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__getstate__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
aaa
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я не уточнил что родительский класс неизменяемый

Answer (score 0):

Тогда тебе не нужно создавать дочерний класс, просто добавь к существующему необходимый атрибут

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
b = Parent()
b.__setattr__("aaa","aaa")
print(b.aaa)
```

Comment: a = Child() создает новый объект, а мне нужно сохранить старый, но добавить к нему новые методы и атрибуты, вот в этом и сложность

Comment: @papadulo, наследуя параметры от родительского класса ты его не изменишь, ты просто создашь класс в котором есть старые и добавятся новые. То что тебе скорее всего нужно - добавить атрибут, посмотри это https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-setattr/

Comment: я неправильно вопрос задал, созданные где-то ранее X и Y нужно тоже сохранить, при создании нового экземпляра они пропадут

Comment: @papadulo, исправил ответ